# Slide Drawer is opening and closing on both left and right gestures iOS object c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, slide

I have been trying to develop an iOS app which have a slide drawer, similar to the navigation drawer in Android... Everything working fine except, the slide drawer can open and close using both left and right swipe gestures...
I need it only close in Left swipe gesture and open using right swipe gesture...

Adding the code below... Please consider that am very new in iOS development..

```
 #import "mainViewController.h"

 @interface mainViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation mainViewController

 @synthesize menuDrawerWidth, menuDrawerX,recognizer_open, recognizer_close;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
menuDrawer = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SlideDrawer" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
menuDrawerWidth= 250 ;
int statusbarHeight= [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
menuDrawerX= self.view.frame.origin.x- menuDrawerWidth;
menuDrawer.frame= CGRectMake(menuDrawerX, menuDrawer.frame.origin.y+statusbarHeight, menuDrawer.frame.size.width, menuDrawer.frame.size.height-statusbarHeight);
// menuDrawer.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.18 green:0.09 blue:0.29 alpha:1.0];
recognizer_close= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];
recognizer_open= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];
recognizer_close.direction= UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
recognizer_open.direction= UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer_close];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer_open];
[self.view addSubview:menuDrawer];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }



   // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little   preparation before navigation
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
  }


 -(void) handleSwipes:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender{
[self drawerAnimation];

 }
 -(void) drawerAnimation{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:-10];
CGFloat new_x = 0;
if(menuDrawer.frame.origin.x<self.view.frame.origin.x)
{
    new_x= menuDrawer.frame.origin.x+menuDrawerWidth;
    UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:menuDrawer.bounds];
    menuDrawer.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    menuDrawer.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    menuDrawer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
    menuDrawer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
    menuDrawer.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
}
else{
    new_x= menuDrawer.frame.origin.x-menuDrawerWidth;
    UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:menuDrawer.bounds];
    menuDrawer.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    menuDrawer.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    menuDrawer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
    menuDrawer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0f;
    menuDrawer.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
}
menuDrawer.frame= CGRectMake(new_x, menuDrawer.frame.origin.y, menuDrawer.frame.size.width, menuDrawer.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
 }


 @end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Mutual Mobile's [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController). It's an amazing drawer library with a lot of features.
If you just need a drawer in your app, I'd recommend to use it.
If you want to learn how to do it yourself, why not having a look at their code ?

Comment: I have checked it out already... but it is slightly different from what i need to do.. While sliding the drawer out it sliding the entire layout to the right... I need the drawer should be above the main view controller similar in the drawer in android...